Generating Equation for randomisation of a long sequence for finding pairwise distance repeats
I am making a python code. I am generating a equation to do permutation. We want to analyze repeats in one sequence of pairwise distance and randomize it and calculate the probability which sequence repeat occur more number of times but it should be done in equation not with the permutation.
For example, I have a
Sequence: ABCA
If we observed how many times one sequence distance appears in one sequence then in above sequence
Distance 1 AA appears  zero time
Distance 2 AA appears zero time
Distance 3 AA appears 1 time
Same goes for others
Distance 1 AB appears  1 time
Distance 2 AB appears zero time
Distance 3 AB appears zero time
Same goes for AC
Distance 1 AC appears  zero time
Distance 2 AC appears 1 time
Distance 3 AC appears zero time
Same goes for BC, BA, CA
If we randomise the sequence it would be like BACA, ABCA, CAAB, CABA, ACBA......
Now we have to calculate the distance in all the sequences like
How many times each pair appears in all the sequences, like Distance 1 AA appears  1 time in x number of sequences
Distance 2 AA appears 2 time in x sequences
Distance 3 AA appears 2 time in x sequences
Then Calculate the probability at each distance. When I do this for large number of sequences combination number goes  more than 10000000000000000000 that very computational
intensive. I need an equation to calculate all the randomization and distance matrix with equation.
My code
import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations, product
import pandas as pd

def calculate_pairwise_distances(sequence, aa1, aa2):
    positions_aa1 = [i for i, x in enumerate(sequence) if x == aa1]
    positions_aa2 = [i for i, x in enumerate(sequence) if x == aa2]
    pairwise_distances = []
    for pos1 in positions_aa1:
        for pos2 in positions_aa2:
            if pos1 != pos2:
                distance = abs(pos1 - pos2)
                pairwise_distances.append(distance)
    return pairwise_distances

def calculate_distribution(sequence, unique_pairs, max_distance):
    distributions = {pair: np.zeros(max_distance, dtype=int) for pair in unique_pairs}
    for pair in unique_pairs:
        aa1, aa2 = pair
        pairwise_distances = calculate_pairwise_distances(sequence, aa1, aa2)
        for dist in pairwise_distances:
            if dist <= max_distance:
                distributions[pair][dist - 1] += 1
    return distributions

def analyze_permutations(original_sequence, max_distance, n_permutations):
    unique_amino_acids = list(set(original_sequence))
    unique_pairs = ["".join(pair) for pair in product(unique_amino_acids, repeat=2)]

    observed_distribution = calculate_distribution(original_sequence, unique_pairs, max_distance)

    # Generate all unique permutations
    all_permutations = list(set(permutations(original_sequence)))
    if n_permutations > len(all_permutations):
        raise ValueError("Requested number of permutations exceeds the total unique permutations available.")

    permutation_distributions = {pair: np.zeros((len(all_permutations), max_distance), dtype=int) for pair in unique_pairs}

    for idx, permuted_sequence in enumerate(all_permutations[:n_permutations]):
        permuted_sequence = ''.join(permuted_sequence)
        perm_distribution = calculate_distribution(permuted_sequence, unique_pairs, max_distance)
        for pair in unique_pairs:
            permutation_distributions[pair][idx] = perm_distribution[pair]

    return observed_distribution, permutation_distributions, all_permutations

def analyze_distribution(distributions, max_distance):
    analysis_result = {}
    for pair, dist_array in distributions.items():
        analysis_result[pair] = np.zeros((max_distance + 1, max_distance), dtype=int)  # Include 0 occurrences
        for dist in range(max_distance):
            counts = np.bincount(dist_array[:, dist], minlength=max_distance + 1)
            counts = counts[:max_distance + 1]  # Ensure counts array matches max_distance length
            for occurrence in range(max_distance + 1):
                analysis_result[pair][occurrence, dist] = counts[occurrence]
    return analysis_result

# Step 1: Take the protein sequence as input
original_sequence = "WAWAA"

# Step 2: Calculate the maximum distance possible
max_distance = len(original_sequence) - 1

# Step 3: Analyze the permutations
n_permutations = 10
observed_distribution, permutation_distributions, all_permutations = analyze_permutations(original_sequence, max_distance, n_permutations)

# Analyze observed sequence
pair_labels = list(observed_distribution.keys())
observed_tables = {}

for pair in pair_labels:
    distribution_matrix = np.zeros((max_distance + 1, max_distance), dtype=int)  # Include 0 occurrences

    # Function to calculate pairwise distances for each pair
    def calculate_pairwise_distances_general(sequence, aa_pair):
        aa1, aa2 = aa_pair
        if aa1 == aa2:
            positions = [i for i, x in enumerate(sequence) if x == aa1]
            pairwise_distances = [abs(positions[i] - positions[j]) for i in range(len(positions)) for j in range(i + 1, len(positions))]
            return pairwise_distances
        else:
            positions_aa1 = [i for i, x in enumerate(sequence) if x == aa1]
            positions_aa2 = [i for i, x in enumerate(sequence) if x == aa2]
            pairwise_distances = [abs(positions_aa1[i] - positions_aa2[j]) for i in range(len(positions_aa1)) for j in range(len(positions_aa2)) if positions_aa1[i] != positions_aa2[j]]
            return pairwise_distances

    # Analyze the original sequence for each pair
    pairwise_distances = calculate_pairwise_distances_general(original_sequence, pair)
    for distance in range(1, max_distance + 1):
        occurrence_count = pairwise_distances.count(distance)
        distribution_matrix[occurrence_count, distance - 1] += 1

    # Convert to a DataFrame for better visualization
    distance_labels = [f'Distance {i+1}' for i in range(max_distance)]
    occurrence_labels = [f'Occurrences {i}' for i in range(max_distance + 1)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(distribution_matrix, index=occurrence_labels, columns=distance_labels)
    observed_tables[pair] = df

# Display the observed tables
for pair, table in observed_tables.items():
    print(f"\nObserved Frequency Table for Pair '{pair}':\n")
    print(table)

# Initialize distribution matrices for all pairs
analysis_tables = {}

for pair in pair_labels:
    sequences = [''.join(perm) for perm in all_permutations[:n_permutations]]
    distribution_matrix = np.zeros((max_distance + 1, max_distance), dtype=int)  # Include 0 occurrences

    # Function to calculate pairwise distances for each pair
    def calculate_pairwise_distances_general(sequence, aa_pair):
        aa1, aa2 = aa_pair
        if aa1 == aa2:
            positions = [i for i, x in enumerate(sequence) if x == aa1]
            pairwise_distances = [abs(positions[i] - positions[j]) for i in range(len(positions)) for j in range(i + 1, len(positions))]
            return pairwise_distances
        else:
            positions_aa1 = [i for i, x in enumerate(sequence) if x == aa1]
            positions_aa2 = [i for i, x in enumerate(sequence) if x == aa2]
            pairwise_distances = [abs(positions_aa1[i] - positions_aa2[j]) for i in range(len(positions_aa1)) for j in range(len(positions_aa2)) if positions_aa1[i] != positions_aa2[j]]
            return pairwise_distances

    # Analyze each sequence for each pair
    for seq in sequences:
        pairwise_distances = calculate_pairwise_distances_general(seq, pair)
        for distance in range(1, max_distance + 1):
            occurrence_count = pairwise_distances.count(distance)
            distribution_matrix[occurrence_count, distance - 1] += 1

    # Convert to a DataFrame for better visualization
    distance_labels = [f'Distance {i+1}' for i in range(max_distance)]
    occurrence_labels = [f'Occurrences {i}' for i in range(max_distance + 1)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(distribution_matrix, index=occurrence_labels, columns=distance_labels)
    analysis_tables[pair] = df

# Display the frequency tables for permuted sequences
for pair, table in analysis_tables.items():
    print(f"\nFrequency Table for Pair '{pair}':\n")
    print(table)

# Additional block to create probability tables
# Initialize the probability tables for all pairs
probability_tables = {}

# Calculate the probability tables
for pair, table in analysis_tables.items():
    # Create a new DataFrame with the values divided by the number of permutations
    prob_df = table / n_permutations
    probability_tables[pair] = prob_df

# Display the probability tables
for pair, prob_table in probability_tables.items():
    print(f"\nProbability Table for Pair '{pair}':\n")
    print(prob_table)

